# Why does my clojure REPL output gibberish?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm prototyping some really basic functionality, but the REPL is outputting totally random stuff.

Just trying to write a function to update a value in a map gives this:

```
fwd.core=> (fn [step] (update {:x 10 :y 10} :x 20) 20)
#object[fwd.core$eval1593$fn__1594 0x3d2da438 "fwd.core$eval1593$fn__1594@3d2da438"]
```

Comment: That's basically the `.toString` from that function "object" as the jvm sees it

Comment: Ah, I get it, I botched my function definition there. But these error messages are really really bad…

Comment: That's not an error message, it is a string representing that function object.  Your code is a totally valid function.  Mind reading is beyond the scope of most compilers.

Comment: This is no "error" - the code you show there is legit and this is the string reprentation of your funktion - while in my repl i get a way shorter name (maybe it changed with 1.10 and you are on some older version?).  if you want a "better" name for that anon-fn, you can name it like : `(fn my-fun [step] ...)`

Comment: I'm trying to learn this. But thanks for clearing this up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funtions are first class citizens in Clojure.  So you defined an anonymous function (mind you, that is close to a no-op here, since you don't hold on to it -- and you had some parens at the wrong place too (see below)) and the RE**P**L printed it for you.

So this is basically the `.toString()` representation of the object of your function the way the JVM sees it.

Sidenote:

To have a bit better naming for your stacktraces, you can name also anon fns like:

```clj
user=> (fn [step] (update {:x 10 :y 10} :x 20) 20)
#<Fn@559d19c user/eval8096[fn]>
user=> (fn my-fancy-name [step] (update {:x 10 :y 10} :x 20) 20)
#<Fn@451816fd user/eval8105[my_fancy_name]>
```

#### edit (there are multiple problems with the function)

As for the function itself, the inner update is a no-op too, since you
are not assigning the result of the update too.  The function now always
returns `20`.

To call the function, you have to fix the parens:

```clj
user=> ((fn [step] (update {:x 10 :y 10} :x step)) 20)
Execution error (ClassCastException) at user/eval8105$fn (REPL:1).
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

(The function is in the first place for the surrounding parens, so it
will be called.

This now gives an error since `update` expects an function - use `assoc`
instead:

```clj
user=> ((fn [step] (assoc {:x 10 :y 10} :x step)) 20)
{:x 20, :y 10}
```

Comment: I was trying to apply the 20 there as a parameter. Don't really understand what happened to that here. It's not complaining, that's for sure.

Comment: @Alper ah now i see your confusion - the function itself looked weird (no offence) so i thought you banged just some forms together and were confused by output alone.  I have added some more explanations regarding the other problems.

Comment: Super duper! A bit of an on-ramp here but it looks manageable.